# FFmpeg on Android add subtitles too slowly

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, android, fontconfig

Recently I use `FFmpeg 4.0` on Android. And I use FFmpeg to add subtitles. But it's very slow. After some check, I find where the problem is.

As you know, FFmpeg should `enable-libass` so that you can add subtitles.

There is code in `libass/libass/ass_fontselect.c`.

```
priv->default_provider =
                font_constructors[i].constructor(library, priv, config);
```

This "constructor" is used to construct a `ASS_FontProvider` and it takes almost **17s+** on my old `Nexus 5`. It's too slow.

Now I know where the problem is. But how to solve it? I believe there are many people like me.

Comment: Did you isolate libass as the bottleneck? Because I would imagine the video encoder would be the slowest process. `ffmpeg -i input -vf drawtext -an -f null -`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Building font cache takes 17s but encoding is very fast.

Comment: How can the issue be duplicated? Does it occur on other systems?

Comment: In my opinion, if you are use ffmpeg on linux, it can occur. Because `fontconfig` building fc-cache will take much time. But I do not know how  to  let it occur.

Comment: Can you provide your `ffmpeg` command?

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf ass=subtitles.ass output.mp4